# How put html code into vb.net without mistake?

Tags: html, vb.net, outlook

I am trying to sent html mail via outlook. I have following mistake. Any support will be appreciated.

Comment: That tries to assign XML (XElement iirc) to htmlBody which must be a string; assign one:  `.htmlBody = "<html> ... </html>"`

Comment: No, all the HTML needs to be in the string

Answer (score 1):

You need to encase all of the Html in a string, such as:

```
.htmlbody = "<html> <body> <h1>This is heading 1</h1> </body> /html>"
```

Anything outside of the string will not be passed to the htmlbody property.